# How can I style shadow parts?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, button, shadow-dom

I want to style the shadow parts of the ion-button, but my code won't work. I have the newest Ionic version.

```html
<template>
    <div class="kitButton">
        <ion-button part="native" class="button-native" v-if="info.title">
            <ion-label  v-on:click="getTree">{{info.title}}</ion-label>
                <ion-button class="favoriteButton" size="small" color="danger" v-on:click="setFavorite">&#10084;</ion-button>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-button class="kitButtonText" part="native" v-if="info.data">
            <ion-label  v-if="info.data.title" v-on:click="getNextLevel">{{info.data.title}}</ion-label>
                <ion-button class="favoriteButton" v-if='isDisabled' size="small" color="danger" v-on:click="setFavorite">&#10084;</ion-button>
         </ion-button>

    </div>
</template>
```

CSS:

```css
ion-button:part(native) {
    color: green;
    background-color: green;
    margin-bottom: 500px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is a typo: `:part` should be [`::part`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts#how-part-works).

Comment: can you use -- on scss propery.. like --background: red; --box-shadow:xyz ?

Comment: See blog post for example, you code is incorrect - https://ionicframework.com/blog/customize-your-ionic-framework-app-with-css-shadow-parts/